# On hover <a> next div fadein and mouseleave on div this div fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

On hover of an `<a>` the next div fadein and mouseleave on div this div fade out but when div fade in and drag my mouse on dive it will go fade out

```js
jQuery('.share_link').hover(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  jQuery(this).next('.quick-view-share').stop().fadeIn();
}, function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  jQuery(this).next('.quick-view-share').not().fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0);" class="share_link"></a>
<div class="quick-view-share" style="display: none;">
  <a class="facebook" href="#" title="Share on Facebook">  Face Book</a>
  <a class="twitter" href="#" title="Tweet"> Twittter</a>
  <a class="google-plus" href="#" title="Share on Google Plus"> G Plus </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the `hover` logic is attached to the `a` element. Therefore as soon as you leave the `a` to select something from the displayed `div`, it immediately disappears.

To solve this you could amend your HTML to hook the events to a containing element. Alternatively you can utilise CSS to make the hover logic work for both elements by using CSS's adjacent sibling operator, `+`:

```css
a.share_link + .quick-view-share {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

a.share_link:hover + .quick-view-share, 
a.share_link + .quick-view-share:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a target="_blank" href="#" class="share_link">Share</a>
<div class="quick-view-share">
  <a class="facebook" href="#" title="Share on Facebook">  Face Book</a>
  <a class="twitter" href="#" title="Tweet"> Twittter</a>
  <a class="google-plus" href="#" title="Share on Google Plus"> G Plus </a>
</div>
```